# Nested parLapply : Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 7 nodes produced errors; first error: invalid connexion

Tags: r, dplyr, parallel-processing, tidyverse, doparallel

I'm trying to execute a code with nested parlapply. My code is as the following:

```
cl <- (snow::makeCluster(detectCores() - 1))

  clusterEvalQ(cl, c(library(dplyr), library(parallel), library(tidyr),library(stringr),library(tidytable)))  

 for (iteration in 1:(NB_REGROUP_MAX - 1)) {

     KHI2_SEUILS_OPTI <- parallel::parLapply(
       cl = cl,
       c(1:10),
       fun = KHI2_OPTI,
       TABLEAU_CONTINGENCE = TABLEAU_CONTINGENCE,
       iteration = iteration
     )
  }
```

So with this first function, I'm calling through a parLapply a second function which also call a parLapply :

```
   KHI2_OPTI <- function(TABLEAU_CONTINGENCE, QUANTILE_DEPART, iteration) {


print(iteration)

KHI2_CONDITIONNEL <- parallel::parLapply(
  cl = cl,
  c(1:QUANTILE_FIN),
  fun = KHI2_CONDITIONNEL,
  TABLEAU_CONTINGENCE = TABLEAU_CONTINGENCE,
  QUANTILE_DEPART = QUANTILE_DEPART,
  iteration = iteration
)
}
```

When executing this, I have the following error :

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :  7 nodes produced errors; first
> error: invalid connection

The aim of this code is to reduce significantly the time execution because of a huge number of iterations.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, my best guess is that you try to pass the cluster object `cl` down to the parallel workers.  That is not possible, and typically result in this type of error. A cluster object can only be used in the R process where it was created.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I used furrr package and it works well now.